# Problems With Recursively Defined Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am having an issue with this problem.

> A  set, *S*,  of  positive  integers  is  defined  recursively  by  the  rule:
>
> 1. $1 \in S$,
> 2. If $n\in S$, then $2n-1 \in S$
>
> List  all  the  elements  in  the  set $S$.

The reason I am having difficulty is because plugging in $1$ into $2n-1$ provides me with the original statement, namely, that $1\in S$

This is far as I have been able to get with the problem and I would appreciate some helpful hints.

Comment: The mapping $S\to S;n\mapsto 2n-1$ is increasing, so $S$ is either equal to $\{1\}$ or infinite. The conditions stated above are not enough to figure out which type of set is.

Comment: @Phoenix: when they say that the set is recursively defined by the rules, that already means it is the smallest set satisfying the rules.

Comment: Recursion theorem allows to build functions recursively, not sets like the set $S$ described above. This set is not defined recursively, since the "recusive step" is about elements in $S$ to describe "which other elements could belong to $S$"... The smallest must be mentioned here, but it is not the case.

Comment: If they said the $n \in S \implies (2n+1)\in S$ then all the  integers of the form $2^k-1$ would be in $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so all that that means is that $1$ is the only element in $S$; it's the only one we put in there as a 'base', and using the 'step', it turns out we can't get any others in there.

Comment: Hmm. I thought about this. That seems rather *easy*. The professor then says "list all elements in $S$." So perhaps, I am looking too far into this.

Comment: @SincerelyPrime I suppose sometimes you just shouldn't overthink things ...

Comment: The conditions 1. & 2.  do not imply that $1$ is the only member of $S$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleetcan Can you elaborate and post an answer? I would love the additional insight in the form of an answer, where you can expand your mathematical thought.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: but the statement that the set is defined as the elements generated by the rule does.

Comment: So, those conditions *do* tell me that $1$ is the only element. Hmm. I appreciate the insight.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet if the statements 1 and 2 would simply be some *claims* about the set, then you would be right, but as a *recursive definition*, you can't put more elements into the set other than those you get through the base, and the step as applied to that base.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your set  $S$ is simply not well-defined...

Taking $S_1 = \mathbb N - \{0\}$, this set satisfy the two conditions stated above.
But $S_2 = \{1\}$ too ! If such a set $S$ is well-defined via 1. & 2., it must be the only set satisfying those conditions, so $S_1 = S_2 = S$... contradiction...

Comment: Technically, the sets are equivalent *only* because they share the same, single, element, $1$. You have merely described another set (using $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ , by the way). Regardless, I think the question posed by this professor is poorly constructed. Partially, in agreement with you, but also because there appears to be some ambiguity within the **structure** of the question. Can you elaborate on your point any further?

Comment: A set $S$ which satisfy the properties 1. and 2. is not unique, hence your problem is not meaningful :/

Comment: He wants us to describe the set $S$, which is $\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. The description in the question provides a set whose only element is $1$. But if I say, describe a set $M$ such that $M\in \mathbb{N}$ and any $x \in {M} \leqslant 1$ then that also provides the set ${1}$. Just because $M=S$ doesn't mean that those descriptions, or those sets, are not *meaningful*.